# how to detect empty body methods in java classes using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-cleanup

I am currently working on project which is 5 years old. Now i am doing code clean up. I found some methods with empty body. As code base is large i want to know if there are any eclipse plugins which can list out methods with empty body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know SonarQube can alert you to those, and there is a SonarQube plugin for Eclipse.
I think it'll work standalone from the Sonarube server, but you won't in that case probably be able to customise the alerts.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need a plugin

In Eclipse Preferences -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Code Style

You have Undocumented empty blocks

if methods with empty body have not documentation you can have a warning/error without plugins

Comment: I think this is the best answer.